# find if a group of characters are contained in a string and delete the group of characters and preceding characters in the string

Tags: python, string

What is the most effective way to remove a group of characters in a string and the preceding characters before the group of characters I have found?

For example, if I have the string given as:

`string = "LightNight\nLiverpool’s annual ‘culture-crawl’ LightNight returns to the city on Friday, May 21, when arts venues will throw open their doors from 5pm until late to shine a spotlight on the region’s world-class artistic offer."`

and group of characters given as:

`group_of_char_str = '\n'`

I want to create a new string
`new_string = "Liverpool’s annual ‘culture-crawl’ LightNight returns to the city on Friday, May 21, when arts venues will throw open their doors from 5pm until late to shine a spotlight on the region’s world-class artistic offer."`

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What should it do if `group_of_char_str` is present multiple times ?

Answer (score 1):

Use find(), then slice the string if index is positive :

```py
string = "Lorem ipsum\ndolor sit amet"
group_of_char_str = '\n'
index = string.find(group_of_char_str) # find index
new_string = string[:]
if index >= 0:
    new_string = string[index+len(group_of_char_str):]
print(new_string)
# > dolor sit amet
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *.split()* method :

```
string = "LightNight\nLiverpool’s annual ‘culture-crawl’ LightNight returns to the city on Friday, May 21, when arts venues will throw open their doors from 5pm until late to shine a spotlight on the region’s world-class artistic offer."

new_string = string.split("\n")[-1]
print(new_string)

#>>> "Liverpool’s annual ‘culture-crawl’ LightNight returns to the city on Friday, May 21, when arts venues will throw open their doors from 5pm until late to shine a spotlight on the region’s world-class artistic offer"
```